# Improve performance of Matlab fill command to plot overlapping confidence bands

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot two (or more series) on one axes, each with several confidence intervals. These confidence intervals may overlap, in which case the desired behavior is for the overlapping area to display as a mixture of both colors. Using the `fill` function to create `patch` objects accomplishes this, as one can set the `FaceAlpha` property. (Using the `area` command results in bands drawing on top of each other and obscuring the content below.) Then, I want to save the resulting figures as high-quality eps files.

Here is an example of working code that accomplishes this:

```
datevec = 0:9;
myMean = 1+rand(1,10)*0.2;
myBounds = [myMean - 0.5;
            myMean - 0.4;
            myMean - 0.3;
            myMean + 0.3;
            myMean + 0.4;
            myMean + 0.5];

myMean1 = linspace(0,2,10)+rand(1,10)*0.2;
myBounds1 = [myMean1 - 0.5;
            myMean1 - 0.4;
            myMean1 - 0.3;
            myMean1 + 0.3;
            myMean1 + 0.4;
            myMean1 + 0.5];

figure();
hold on;
plot(datevec,myMean);
plot(datevec,myMean1);
nBands = size(myBounds,1)/2;
for iBand = 1:nBands
    fill([datevec, fliplr(datevec)],...
         [myBounds(iBand,:), fliplr(myBounds(nBands*2+1-iBand,:))],...
         'r', 'FaceAlpha', 0.1*iBand);
    fill([datevec, fliplr(datevec)],...
         [myBounds1(iBand,:), fliplr(myBounds1(nBands*2+1-iBand,:))],...
         'b', 'FaceAlpha', 0.1*iBand);
end
hold off;
```

The problem comes in saving this figure. The default behavior seems to be using the OpenGL bitmap renderer, which not only renders low-quality images, but takes a relatively long time. (I conclude that the OpenGL renderer is default by noting that the exact same timing is produced by either specifying or omitting the `'-opengl'` flag below.)

```
tic;
print(gcf(),'-opengl', '-depsc2', 'figure_opengl.eps');
fprintf(1,'Figure saved (opengl) in %f\n', toc); % 6.162832 seconds
```

Forcing the painters renderer, as would appear to be correct for vector images, is substantially faster, but the resulting eps file does not display the transparency of the bands correctly - it is as if `FaceAlpha` were set to `1`.

```
tic;
print(gcf(),'-painters', '-depsc2', 'figure_painters.eps');
fprintf(1,'Figure saved (painters) in %f\n', toc); % 0.301429 seconds
```

So the difference in performance is a factor of 20. Furthermore, if I increase the resolution of the bitmap image by adding the `-r500` flag, the time is on the order of 24 seconds for this example. I want high-quality figures saved, but I can't allow 25 seconds for each figure to simply print to disk.

How can I improve the performance of my code above? Is there an alternative to `fill` that still allows bands to overlap? Are `patch` objects conceived of better as bitmap or vector images? Should I be changing the settings I use to print these files? Any help is appreciated.

Matlab 14a on GNU/Linux. I can attach the images the code produces if desired.

Comment: Using opengl with EPS Level 3 (`'-depsc'`) takes ~1/3 of time to save the figure in comparison to Level 2 (`'-depsc2'`) over here.

Comment: `tic; saveas(gcf(), 'test.epsc'); toc;` takes 2s on my computer (Matlab 14a on Windows). I would considers this being fast enough.